# M2: How is the bundle price in the category page defined?

Tags: magento2, category, bundled-product

I have a bundle consisting out of 2 simple products. I don't understand the price which gets displayed before I customize the bundle. How is it set up? $21 is clear, but why does it show $69 in first place?

Image 1

[image]

Image 2

[image]

After I press `Customize and Add to Cart` the price shows different and understandable. Below you can see my configuration, pretty standard I would think

[image]

Answer (score 1):

(see follow-up below)

It looks like your bundle product is set to Fixed pricing. Is that correct?  I duplicated your scenario, and ran into a similar problem when Dynamic Pricing was disabled in the bundle product.  Have you tried creating the bundle product with Dynamic Pricing set to the default "Yes"?  That worked OK for me.  Meanwhile, I'll report this as a possible bug.

BTW, questions related to the Admin can be submitted through the Feedback form, which is at the bottom of each user guide page.

Thanks so much for bringing it to our attention.

Claire Condra, Head of Merchant Documentation

Comment: Yes, Dynamic Pricing is disabled. I haven't tried with the option being enabled because this doesn't match my use case ;-)
Thank you for reporting...

Answer (score 1):

I revisited this today and discovered that it now works correctly, which makes me think that the cache wasn't cleared.  Both the catalog listing and the product page display $21.00, which is the correct price of the default bundle items.  The fixed pricing settings I used are:

Price: 0.00
Dynamic Price: No
Bundle Items:
Simple1, Price 4.0, Default Qty: 2
Simple2, Price 5.0, Default Qty: 1

I'll post anything more that I learn here.

Claire

Comment: Obviously clearing cache was the first thing I tried. Please see my configuration here: http://imgur.com/a/HnH2p
Is there anything different to your setup?